# Rails: one of many parents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through, has-many

If I have a model that can belong to one of ten other models, will I need ten different `_id` attributes in the model, leaving nine blank with every record? Or is there a better way to arrange it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jakub suggests, you can use a [polymorphism](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) as follows:

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo, polymorphic: true
  ...
end

class Foo1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars, as: :foo
  ...
end

class Foo2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars, as: :foo
  ...
end

...

class Foo9 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars, as: :foo
end
```

This will use a single `id` attribute in the `bars` table, but include an extra type field to specify which `foo` type it's referring to.

Answer (score 1):

How about polymorphic association? If you need one model belonging to to many others models.Then you just need _id and _type which wont be empty.http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

I need ten different _id attributes in the model, leaving nine blank with every record? - NO